# New Generalized MR-test

Tags: number-theory, primality-test

I am conducting a new Miller Rabin (SPRP test) and editing the first step. Can someone please help me with the last step. Thanks.

Original: Write $n$ $=$ $2^sd+1$ with $d$ odd. Replace:

New Test: Write $n$ $=$ $b^sd+1$ with $d$ not a multiple of $b$.

The second step to the test is the same as the original Miller Rabin Test:

Original: If $a^d$ = $1 \pmod n$ or $a^{2^td} =$ $-1$ $\pmod n$ where $0$ $<$ $t$ $<$ $s$, then $n$ is an $a$-SPRP.

New Test: If If $a^d$ = $1 \pmod n$ then $n$ is an $a$-SPPP.

I am confused at this part:

If $a^{b^td} =$ $x$ $\pmod n$ where $0$ $<$ $t$ $<$ $s$, then $n$ is an $a$-SPRP.

Shouldn't there be $b$ choices for $x$? I do not know how to find these possibilities for $x$.

Comment: Can we speak about a SPRP in the case of a base $b\ne 2$ ? I do not think so.

Comment: I do think it is possible given $b$ divides $n-1$, but how the $b$th residues are distributed, I am not sure.